# Session Environment Variables for Windows CMD shell

Tags: windows, cmd, session-variables

I understand from my googling that on *nix systems you can use the `export` command to set a temporary environment variable for the current session. What's the Windows equivalent for the plain old CMD shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that `SET` is the equivalent of `export`.

Furthermore, to reference the variable, it needs to be surrounded by percent signs:

```
SET MY_VARIABLE=42
echo %MY_VARIABLE%
```

SET documentation: ss64.com/nt/set.html